# Getter of property in Realm search/save doesnt work?

Tags: objective-c, realm

I need to create extra property for reason mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760078/nsdiacriticinsensitivepredicateoption-not-supported-by-realm). I tried to do it using getter, which resolves the value of original property, like this:

```
Pubs.h

@property NSString *pubname; // original property
@property NSString *pubnameDS; // extra property with diacritics stripped
.
.
- (NSString*) pubnameDS;

Pubs.m:

// it refers to property "pubname" and it does striping of diacritics
- (NSString*) pubnameDS {

    NSMutableString *string = [self.pubname mutableCopy];
    CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)(string),
                      NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, NO);

    return string;
}
```

So this works as expected:

```
Pubs *p = [[Pubs alloc] init];
p.pubname = @"čulukánas";

DLog(@"%@ %@ %@", p.pubname, p.pubnameDS, [p pubnameDS]);
```

But, if I insert data in "db" with filled pubname property and empty pubnameDS and I expect that Realm will use getter for property pubnameDS when doing search (or save), it seems it doesnt work like that.

Because this finds data:

```
DLog(@"classic search res %lu", [[Pubs objectsWhere:@"pubname CONTAINS[c] 'club'"] count]);
```

But this not:

```
DLog(@"classic search res %lu", [[Pubs objectsWhere:@"pubnameDS CONTAINS[c] 'club'"] count]);
```

Btw extra another problem - this doesnt work at all (Why? It always returns 0 results)

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pubname CONTAINS[c] '%@'", @"club"];
DLog(@"predicate res %lu", [[Pubs objectsWithPredicate:pred] count]);
```

Simply cant make NSPredicate search working, dont know what is the reason.

But back to the original problem, that Realm does not use getter for property when searching, so it seems the only solution is to manually set the extra property before saving to db.

May be another solution could be refer to original property value from defaultPropertyValues method, but as that is static method that's not solution I guess (because it does not refer to actual instance of object)

**Edit:** hmm if I insert that one created object to db, then it seems pubnameDS is also set, but my case was I was saving the data via following method

```
        id object = [self createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withJSONDictionary:dictionary];
```

then it is probably clear, why is not the getter called, since it is general object, not instance of Pubs, when saving.

**Edit2**

As for the not functional predicate. I found that while this doesnt work:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pubname CONTAINS[c] '%@'", @"club"];
```

This does work. Interesting.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pubname CONTAINS[c] 'club'"];
```

**Edit3:**

This also works, perhaps it is the correct approach, dont know. (omitted aphostrophes around %@)

```
pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pubname CONTAINS[c] %@", @"club"];
```

Realm 0.98.6

Comment: use the latest version of realm

Comment: i could try it, but i am using ABFRealmMapView which pod is dependant on RBQFetchedResultsController pod, but I think there is incompability between latest Realm pod and RBQFetchedResultsController pod, so i had to use older Realm version. Anyways, you know why NSPredicate doesnt work?

Comment: did you try any other sample task of realm?

Comment: yes, saving data, and retrieving all data, also the classical search as shown above works (method objectsWhere). i also updated my post regarding predicate problem. thanks for you help

Comment: Did you get result?

Comment: If you get the answer please post the answer here because it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

1. Only persisted properties on your objects can be used in queries. Attempting to use a non-persisted property such as your `pubnameDS` will fail as Realm's query engine has no way to access the property.
2. `NSPredicate`'s format strings behave differently than the usual format strings used by `NSString` and the like as they're used to build up an expression tree. In particular, the `%@` format specifier inserts the object at the given point in the expression tree. It doesn't insert a string representation as it would with `NSString`. This is why you were seeing issues when wrapping the `%@` specifier with quotes.