# Diacritic-insensitive filtering with Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, search, realm, diacritics

I have an app and I would like to know if it is possible that if I try to find a street based on its name, for example "ceska", my app can match a street whose name contains diacritics, such as "Česká".

I've tried using:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)
```

When using `name contains[d]` it doesn't work.

Comment: It would need to be `contains[cd]` to be both case and diacritic insensitive.

Comment: @dan I tried it but xcode shows error - 'NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption not supported for string type'

Comment: Realm doesn't support diacritic insensitive filtering apparently. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760078/nsdiacriticinsensitivepredicateoption-not-supported-by-realm

Comment: I saw this but i would like to solved. Is there some another solution?

Comment: Either do the workaround that the answer to that question suggests or wait for Realm to add support for diacritic insensitive filtering.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much for your answer. :-)

Comment: @dan Implemented 6 days ago, merged yesterday! We just have to wait for the next release.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are three search variants of the lowercase letter `č`. There is the without-diacritics lowercase variant `c`,  the uppercase variant `Č` and the uppercase without-diacritics variant `C`.

Option `d` in `contains` controls the diacritics.
Option `c` in `contains` controls case sensitivity.

If you are looking for text `ceska` then:

- `contains` will find only `ceska` (exact match)
- `contains[c]` will find `ceska` and `Ceska`
- `contains[d]` will find `ceska` and `česka`
- `contains[cd]` will find `ceska`, `česka`, `Ceska` and `Česka`

The diacritic-insensitive modifier is supported as of [Realm Swift v2.5.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v2.5.0).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried contains[cd] it but uxcode shows error - 'NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption not supported for string type'.

Comment: @spread7 Oh, that seems to be Realm limitation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760078/nsdiacriticinsensitivepredicateoption-not-supported-by-realm.